# How do I know if an specific position of an dynamic allocated array is NULL?

Tags: pointers

If I declare an array like:

```
int *array; 
array=(int *)malloc(10*sizeof(int));
```

And... I want to know if the array[5] is empty, what could I do?

```
if(*array[5]==NULL){
    printf("is it correct? ");
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `calloc` to zero-initialise the array

Comment: There is no such thing as "empty". You have to rethink.

Answer (score 1):

If you fill the array with NULLs before doing anything with it, then put NULL in an array slot after 'emptying' it, then yes, then you need code like so:

```
if (array[5] == NULL) {
    printf("Cell 5 is empty");
}
```

You don't need the `*`.

Also, malloc won't prefill this with NULLs, so don't rely on that.

Note however that in this case, putting NULLs in the array wouldn't make much sense.  NULL is a special value for an empty *pointer*, which the individual elements of `array` are not.  In this case, you'd want to just store some other 'empty' value, such as 0 or -1, as your situation demands.

If you *did* want `array` to store pointers, you need to change its declaration to something like this:

`int **array`

Which makes it a double pointer, or an array of pointers depending on how you use it.  Allocating it could work like so:

```
int **array;
array = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 10);
```

At that point, each element of `array` is a pointer, which you could then dereference with the `*` operator.

Comment: When you say fill the array with nulls, I think something like this:   for(i=0;i<10;i++){ array[i]=NULL; } is it correct?

Comment: @FrankProgamer Yes, that's one way to do it.  There are also some standard library functions you can use to initialize blocks of memory to a value, but that's the most obvious way.

Comment: Telgin, but... if I try to do that, "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast"

Comment: @FrankProgamer Oh, wait, yes that makes sense.  Sorry, NULL is a pointer, but the individual elements of array are not pointers.  If you want them to be pointers, you need to declare array as `int **array`.  If you just want integers in array, then you want to assign 0 instead, or some other 'empty' value.  I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

No use * or []
use

```
*(array+5) == NULL
```

or

```
array[5] == NULL
```

but not both since array is a pointer to an int, or an int array (it is the same thing, it depends how you want to see it).
`*array[5]` would be the integer pointed by the int pointer at slot 5, equivalent to `**(array+5)`.
Beware that you must set your memory to 0 after malloc if you want to test NULL.
with memset(array, 0, 10*sizeof(int)).

Comment: could I use a for to fill my array with NULLS?

Comment: @Frank yes you can, but it would be less efficient memset is often  otptimzed in assembly

Comment: but... if I try to do that, "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast", anyway, thanks for helping

Comment: Oops, I think I just misleaded ... integers are not objects in C, and hence not pointers ... testing with NULL is equivalent to test with 0 but is it what you want ? 0 = NULL ? to compile this, you  have to cast. However, Though my remarks about pointer arithmetic are valids, I think Luchian has the best answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`array[5]` is an un-initialized `int`. `array[5]` already returns the `int` at that location, since `array` is an `int*`, so dereferencing it doesn't make sense.

It's not empty, and it's also illegal to read from it.